# Anonymize the programs from your terminal with-torify

Tags: tor, ubuntu-server

By using this tutorial  [Torify app terminal](http://linuxaria.com/howto/how-to-anonymize-the-programs-from-your-terminal-with-torify)

I find this error

```
*WARNING torsocks[5359]: [connect] Connection to a local address are denied since it might
 be a TCP DNS query to a local DNS server. Rejecting it for safety reasons. (in tsocks_connect() at connect "
.c:186)*
```

knows how to patch this?

Ubuntu server 16.04
My command: sudo torify python3 torPython.py

My code here:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen                                                                         
from stem import Signal                                                                                    
from stem.control import Controller                                                                        

with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:                                                      
    controller.authenticate(password='dummy123456admin')                                                      
    print("Success!")                                                                                      
    controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)                                                                       
    print("New Tor connection processed")                                                                  
    print(urlopen('http://icanhazip.com').read())
```

Comment: This may interest you. https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/16765

Comment: Please sum up shortly the linked information so that people who want to help don't have to read more than your question.

Comment: What does your Python software do? According to the message it tries tp connect to a private IP address (10.a.b.c, 192.168.a.b etc.).

Comment: upgrade my question

Comment: You shouldn't run your script through Torify, since you want to connect to the controller locally from localhost.  Just `sudo python3 torPython.py` should suffice.